# Angular 1.6 Custom validation directive with $setValidity

Tags: angularjs, validation, directive, angularjs-1.6

I'm attempting to write a custom directive that validates a input field against other values that also needs to available inside the directive. I do this by using isolated scope with scope variables. More specifically I would like to compare the customer-price of a product (i.e. its netprice) with the purchase price and if the differece is negative (with the exception of the customer price being set to 0) I'd like to make the customer-price input (and its surrounding form) invalid. Here's my directive:

```
export class CheckMarkupDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public static create(): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: "ngModel",
            scope: {
                netPrice: "<",
                markupAmount: "<"
            },
            link: (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, ngModelCtrl: ng.INgModelController) => {

                let netPrice: number;
                let markupAmount: number;
                scope.$watchGroup(["netPrice", "markupAmount"], (newValues, oldValues) => {

                    [netPrice, markupAmount] = newValues;

                    if (markupAmount >= 0) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setValidity("markup", true);
                    } else {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setValidity("markup", netPrice === 0);
                    }
                    ngModelCtrl.$validate();
                });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm using it inside a a ng-form div surrounded by a form-tag:

```
<input type="text" id="customer-price" name="customerPrice"
       ng-model="ctrl.product.customerPrice"
       ng-change="ctrl.customerPriceChangeDetected()" 
       check-markup markup-amount="ctrl.product.markupAmount"
       net-price="ctrl.product.netPrice" />
```

It works, after a fashion but the problem is that the validation part seems to be "timed wrong", meaning that if I enter a value that causes the "markup" to become negative the first time, then the form's $invalid value is set to false. But when next the input is negative then the validation will kick in and work. I think my problem is that I'm doing a lot of calculations in between the differen steps, but it's hard for me to know what's causing the validation to be so off. I guess I'd like someone with a deeper knowledge of the Angular JS mechanics to have gander and tell me if I'm doing something obviously wrong. Thanks in advance and sorry if my description is kind of vague.

**Edit:** Thought I'd also include the methods that are triggered on ng-change:

```
public customerPriceChangeDetected(): void {
    this.setNetPriceFromCustomerPrice();
    this.setMarkup();
    this.changeDetected();
}
private setNetPriceFromCustomerPrice(): void {
    let customerPrice = this.product.customerPrice;
    let vatRate = this.product.vatRate;
    let netPrice = (customerPrice / (1 + vatRate));
    this.product.netPrice = parseFloat(accounting.toFixed(netPrice, 2));
}
private setMarkup(): void {
    let purchasePrice = this.product.purchasePrice;
    let markupAmount = this.product.netPrice - purchasePrice;
    this.product.markupAmount = markupAmount;
    this.product.markupPercent = markupAmount / purchasePrice;
}
public changeDetected(): void {
    let isValid = this.validationService ? this.validationService.isValid : false;
    this.toggleSaveButton(isValid);
}
```

The validation service getter basically returns form.$valid and works perfectly fine for all my other custom validators.

**Edit 2:** Added screenshot that show that the surrounding ng-form tag seems to have its $invalid property set to true atleast:
[image]

**Edit 3:**
Here's the transpiled JS:

```
var CheckMarkupDirective = (function () {
function CheckMarkupDirective() {
}
CheckMarkupDirective.create = function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            netPrice: "<",
            markupAmount: "<"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var netPrice;
            var markupAmount;
            scope.$watchGroup(["netPrice", "markupAmount"], function (newValues, oldValues) {
                netPrice = newValues[0], markupAmount = newValues[1];
                if (!markupAmount || !netPrice)
                    return;
                if (markupAmount >= 0) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity("markup", true);
                }
                else {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity("markup", netPrice === 0);
                }
                //ngModelCtrl.$validate();
            });
        }
    };
};
return CheckMarkupDirective; }());
```

...and here's a cut down version of my html:

```
<form autocomplete="off" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="productDetailsForm" novalidate data-ng-init="ctrl.setForm(this,'productDetailsForm')">
<div data-ng-form="section2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="purchase-price" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Purchase price</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="purchase-price" name="purchasePrice"
                   data-ng-model="ctrl.product.purchasePrice"
                   data-ng-change="ctrl.purchasePriceChangeDetected();"
                   data-decimal="Currency" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="vat-rate" class="col-sm-4 control-label">VAT rate</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control" id="vat-rate"
                    data-ng-model="ctrl.product.vatRate"
                    data-ng-change="ctrl.vatRateChangeDetected()"
                    data-ng-options="vatRate.value as vatRate.text for vatRate in ctrl.vatRates"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" data-has-error-feedback="productDetailsForm.section2.customerPrice">
        <label for="customer-price" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Customer price</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer-price" name="customerPrice"
                   data-ng-model="ctrl.product.customerPrice"
                   data-ng-change="ctrl.customerPriceChangeDetected();"
                   data-decimal="Currency"
                   data-check-markup
                   data-markup-amount="ctrl.product.markupAmount"
                   data-net-price="ctrl.product.netPrice" />
            <invalid-feedback item="productDetailsForm.section2.customerPrice"></invalid-feedback>
            <validation-feedback type="markup" item="productDetailsForm.section2.customerPrice" data-l10n-bind="ADMINISTRATION.PRODUCTS.NET_PRICE.INVALID"></validation-feedback>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                <label for="net-price" class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" style="font-weight: normal; margin-top: 7px;">
                    <span data-l10n-bind="ADMINISTRATION.PRODUCTS.NET_PRICE"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7" style="font-weight: normal; margin-top: 7px;">
                    <span id="net-price">{{ ctrl.product.netPrice | currency }}</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" data-has-error-feedback="productDetailsForm.section2.markup">
        <label for="markup-amount" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">Markup</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <label id="markup-percent" class="control-label" data-ng-class="{'text-danger': ctrl.product.markupPercent < 0}">
                {{ ctrl.product.markupPercent * 100 | number: 2 }}%
            </label>
            <label id="markup-amount" class="control-label" data-ng-class="{'text-danger': ctrl.product.markupAmount < 0}">
                ({{ ctrl.product.markupAmount | currency }})
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've put breakpoints inside the watch in the directive and for some weird reason the watch doesn't seem to trigger the first time I enter a new value into the customer-price input. Instead I find myself directly inside the changeDetected() method. I'm really confused now. I think the problem has something todo with the ng-change directive triggering before the validation. I probably has a faulty logic there which results in the isValid check of my validation service triggering before the directive has had time to actually alter the validity.

Comment: I'am not sure to understand why you call `$validate()`. Furthermore ng-change is not called when a field marked invalidbecause ng-model won't get updated on an invalid value. So try to print outside of the form the value of `customerPrice/markupAmount/netPrice` to see if the value is refreshed.

Comment: Hi and thanks for taking the time to help me. I've used console.log inside the watch to see that the markupAmount and netprice gets updated everytime I change the value of the customer-price input field so that part atleast seems to work as expected(?) It seems to me that the validation is always one step behind so that if I start with a valid input and changes it into a invalid one (negative markup) the form will still have $invalid=false. The really annoying part is that the div with ng-form seems to have $invalid=true Whick really confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the isolate scope and evaluate the attributes directly:

```
export class CheckMarkupDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public static create(): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: "ngModel",
            /* REMOVE isolate scope
            scope: {
                netPrice: "<",
                markupAmount: "<"
            },
            */
            link: (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, ngModelCtrl: ng.INgModelController) => {

                let netPrice: number;
                let markupAmount: number;
                //scope.$watchGroup(["netPrice", "markupAmount"],
                //WATCH attributes directly
                scope.$watchGroup([attrs.netPrice, attrs.markupAmount], (newValues, oldValues) => {

                    [netPrice, markupAmount] = newValues;

                    if (markupAmount >= 0) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setValidity("markup", true);
                    } else {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setValidity("markup", netPrice === 0);
                    }
                    ngModelCtrl.$validate();
                });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The `input`, `ng-model`, and `ng-change` directives expect an element without scope. This removes the one-time binding watchers and the complications of an isolate scope fighting those directives.

Comment: Tried removing the isolate scope and using attrs.markupAmount and attrs.netPrice instead but I still get the same behaviour. I didn't know the part about ng-model and ng-change not expecting scope though. Not sure if I understand it really either. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduce what I think your form is doing and I have no problem if I add the `ng-change` on **all** fields (vatRate, purchasePrice, customerPrice).

Can you check if what I did match do what your typescript give ? If not can you try to show us the result as javascript ?

```js
angular.module('test',[]).directive('checkMarkup', [function(){
  return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: "ngModel",
            scope: {
                netPrice: "<",
                markupAmount: "<"
            },
            link: (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) => {
                var netPrice;
                var markupAmount;
                scope.$watchGroup(["netPrice", "markupAmount"], (newValues, oldValues) => {
                    netPrice= newValues[0];
                    markupAmount = newValues[1];
                    if (markupAmount >= 0) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setValidity("markup", true);
                    } else {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setValidity("markup", netPrice === 0);
                    }
                    ngModelCtrl.$validate();
                });
            }
        };
}]).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.customerPriceChangeDetected = function(){
    setNetPriceFromCustomerPrice();
    setMarkup();
    
};
function setNetPriceFromCustomerPrice() {
    var customerPrice = $scope.product.customerPrice;
    var vatRate = parseFloat($scope.product.vatRate);
    var netPrice = (customerPrice / (1 + vatRate));
    $scope.product.netPrice = netPrice;
};
function setMarkup(){
    var purchasePrice = $scope.product.purchasePrice;
    var markupAmount = $scope.product.netPrice - purchasePrice;
    $scope.product.markupAmount = markupAmount;
    $scope.product.markupPercent = markupAmount / purchasePrice;
}
}]);
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="form">
      purchasePrice : <input type="text"  name="purchasePrice"
       ng-model="product.purchasePrice"
       ng-change="customerPriceChangeDetected()" 
        />  <br/>
   vatRate : <input type="text"  name="vatRate"
       ng-model="product.vatRate"
       ng-change="customerPriceChangeDetected()" 
        />  <br/>
    
  Customer price : <input type="text" id="customer-price" name="customerPrice"
       ng-model="product.customerPrice"
       ng-change="customerPriceChangeDetected()" 
       check-markup markup-amount="product.markupAmount"
       net-price="product.netPrice" /> <br/>
  </form>
  markupAmount : {{product.markupAmount}} <br/>
  netPrice : {{product.netPrice}} <br/>
  vatRate : {{$scope.product.vatRate}}
   customerPrice invalid : {{form.customerPrice.$invalid}}<br/>
  form invalid : {{form.$invalid}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I've managed to narrow it down to my ng-change method customePriceChangeDetected firing off my validation service's isValid-check (of the form) before the directive has had any chance to actually change the validity of the customer-price input. Guess I need to rethink the logic a bit.

Comment: $watch are triggered at the end of the angular loop. What is strange is that with that sample, I don't reproduce your problem. Your logic seems strange to me too, what I would do would be just to pass your whole product object to your directive and perform all the operations within the directive (use two-way binding to be able to update netPrice/markupAmount)

Comment: You're probably right. The thing is that I started out with the calculations already in place inside the controller for the productDetailsForm and then at a later stage the requirement that you shouldn't be able to save with a negative markup was added which is why I've been thinking about my directive purely as a custom validation and not something that actually performs any calculations.

Comment: @Kristopher Well i'm still interested to know why it doesn't work. Note that in some cases, you can just handle validation in the controller, after the content view is loaded, your form will be under `this.<formName>.<inputName>`. It's obviously not the recommanded option in most of cases but masking the thing about net price / markupAmount within a directive where they're needed at higher level to be registered doesn't seems a regular usage of it too.

Comment: I'm still struggling with all the Angular 1.x concepts (and I have a feeling that observables in Angular 2 is going to give me a lot of grief) but as I understand it, the controller should not be "aware" of the view (i.e. no DOM-manipulation inside the controller)? Anyway my problem was (is) that the ng-change call fires before the watch inside the directive is triggered and among other things the change-method triggers the validation service so that it validates the form before the directive has had any chance to do its stuff. That's how I figure it anyway.

Comment: @Kristofer this is right, no DOM manipulation, there are directives for that. However most of controllers are generally used once only in the whole application. So having a controller bound to a view, or required a view having a form <formName> with an input <inputName> is acceptable. The problem with your code is that, you watch some values which get updated after another one changed, those two level of indirection are effecitively not the standard usage for angularjs.

Comment: I'll probably end up turning the entire economy-section of the form into a separate 1.5-component with its own logic. Thanks for all the input, I appreciate it. I think I have enough information to come up with a working solution but as there is no definitive answer to my vague question that I can mark as such I'll just leave it as is.